# Scala compilation error (s"")

Tags: scala

I have this line of code:

```
val message: String = s"{\"contentId\" : \"$item\"}"
```

When I compile it I get this error:

```
Error:(256, 48) ';' expected but string literal found.
          val message: String = s"{\"contentId\" : \"$item\"}"
                                               ^
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Marked this one as duplicate because linked question is more general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that escaping the quotes confuses the parser / macro, but a simple workaround would be:

```
val message: String = s"""{"contentId" : "$item"}"""
```

Comment: See also https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6476